# What is the perl equivalent to Java's Double.doubleToLongBits()?

Tags: perl, ieee-754

I have two floating point numbers and I want to compute their difference in Units in Last Place (ULP). In Java this is:

```
Double.doubleToLongBits(a) - Double.doubleToLongBits(b)
```

What is the equivalent in Perl?

Comment: The result of `Double.doubleToLongBits()` includes the sign and exponent. That method can fail if `a` and `b` have different exponent values.

Comment: @KeithThompson true it is no longer multiples of the unit in last place but it is a measure of floating point accuracy. I.e. how many numbers are in between a and b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a Perl with double-precision floats<sup>[1]</sup> and unsigned integers at least 64 bits in size<sup>[2]</sup>, you can use the following:

```
unpack('Q', pack('d', $n))
```

For example,

```
$ perl -e'
   use Config qw( %Config );

   die("Not supported\n")
      if $Config{nvsize} != 8
      || $Config{uvsize} < 8;

   printf("%X\n", unpack("Q", pack("d", -0.1)));
'
BFB999999999999A
```

---

1. `perl -V:nvsize` gives `8`
2. `perl -V:uvsize` gives `8` or higher